# Python crash course Alien Invasion movement

Tags: python

There is no error when running the code but the ship is unable to move left or right and I'm sure I did everything right so here's all the code. The ship displays correctly but does not move at all.

```
import pygame
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from settings import Settings


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    game_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_settings.screen_width, game_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    space_ship = Ship(screen)

    while True:
        gf.check_events(space_ship)
        gf.update_screen(game_settings, screen, space_ship)
        space_ship.update()


run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_colour = (0, 0, 255)
```

ship.py

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        # Initializing the ship
        self.screen = screen

        # Load the ship and get the rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False


    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame


def check_events(spaceship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                spaceship.moving_right = True
            elif event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceship.moving_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                spaceship.moving_right = False
            elif event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceship.moving_left = False


def update_screen(game_settings, screen, spaceship):
    screen.fill(game_settings.bg_colour)
    spaceship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

That is all the code I have been able to do. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In pygame, use `event.type` to check for a key event. Use `event.key` to check which key is pressed.

```
def check_events(spaceship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # event.type
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:  # event.key
                spaceship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceship.moving_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                spaceship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceship.moving_left = False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike67